# Area calculated within classification program is different from area calculated by resulting exported image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate area of one class (crop). In the program, the area calculation is taking place perfectly. The classification result image, generated from same program was exported to GEE asset.
When I am trying to calculate the area using exported classified imagery, the area figure comes drastically different and high.
I have so many counties to classify separately. Therefore, there is need to classify and export and then calculate the area of crop for each county or sub-county.

Link to the code is given below-
https://code.earthengine.google.com/7c77c5c647c5c3ff02dfa45c71d8df04

In the code, First area chart is originally calculated area and second one is area by exported class image.
Original area-

[image]

area by exported class image (drastically different and high area)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calculating areas you should always be very specify about projections, transformations, and scale. If you zoom way in so that you can see individual pixels of the two classified image layers, you will notice that they don't match up - the difference may be causing the difference in area calculation.

Use the `reduceRegion` function (instead of the chart function) so that you can specify a `crsTransform` and also export the image with a defined `crsTransform` you will achieve the same area result from both the on-the-fly calculation and the exported image calculation.

Here is an extension to your script that specifies the `crsTransform` for region reduction and image export so that all analyses of area are working with data in the exact same projection, scale, and transformation.

```js
// Get projection information.
var projTemplateImg = sentinelCollection.first().select(1);
// print(projTemplateImg) // <-- Get the band's crs_transform component.
var crsTransform = [10, 0, 499980, 0, -10, 2700000]; // <-- From projTemplateImg band's crs_transform component.
var crs = projTemplateImg.projection().crs();

// Compute area of given class.
var riceeArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000000).updateMask(Ricee)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: region1,
    crs: crs,
    crsTransform: crsTransform,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

// Print the area.
print('riceeArea', riceeArea.get('area'));

//Export to asset.
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: Ricee,
  region: region1,
  assetId: 'CropClass',
  description: 'CropClass',
  maxPixels:1e13,
  pyramidingPolicy: {classification: 'sample'},
  crs: crs,
  crsTransform: crsTransform
});

// Import image after export completes.
var riceeImport = ee.Image('users/USERNAME/CropClass'); // <-- update image ID. 

// Compute area of given class.
var riceeImportArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000000).updateMask(riceeImport)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: region1,
    crs: crs,
    crsTransform: crsTransform,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

// Print the area.
print('riceeImportArea', riceeImportArea.get('area'));
```

[Complete script link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6f7fd083aa8d91634c2f7df9a68b2808)

Comment: Thanks, James. I was not aware of 'crsTransform: crsTransform'. This did the job for me. I tried everything except this. Thanks.